# Increase length and spacing of underline in pie chart title

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a title in a pie chart in Excel 2007 whose text is underlined.

Can I make the line **space between text and the underline larger** and make the **underline longer than the text** itself?

I tried to add space before and after the text but the underline does not extend out with the white space.

This is what I have right now:

[image: The title I have now]

This is what I want:

[image: The title I want]

VBA solutions are also welcome!

Comment: Well, I wish, but I don't make the decisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with 'normal' text editing. Add a line break (to allow a wider than normal gap between text and underline), fill the width with sufficient text (eg lots of `.`s), set the font of this added text to the same colour as its background and change the underline colour to suit (probably black) in Font after right-clicking on the Title box.

*Edit re clarification request*

[image: SO19590273 example]

Comment: Thanks pnuts, but how do you make the underline a different colour from its text (lots of . s)?